# How to fix "Cannot invoke 'createEvent' with an argument list of type '(eventStore: EventStoring)'"

Tags: swift, generics, initialization, protocols, eventkit

I'm working with `EventKit's` `EKEventStore` and I want to mock it and also EKEvent.
But I don't know how to abstract `EKEvent's` `init(eventStore: EKEventStore)` and other methods properly.

```
protocol EventStoring {

    associated type Event: EventStoreEvent where Event.MatchingEventStore == Self

    func save(_ event: Event, span: EKSpan, commit: Bool) throws

    // Other methods of EKEventStore I use
 }

extension EKEventStore: EventStoring {
    typealias Event = EKEvent
}

protocol EventStoreEvent {
    associatedtype MatchingEventStore: EventStoring

    static func createEvent(eventStore: MatchingEventStore) -> Self
}

extension EKEvent: EventStoreEvent {
    typealias MatchingEventStore = EKEventStore

    static func createEvent(eventStore: MatchingEventStore) -> Self {
        return EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore) as! Self 
    }
}
```

Here the errors are: "'Self' is only available in a protocol or as the result of a method in a class; did you mean `'EKEvent'`?" 
and: "Cannot convert return expression of type `'EKEvent'` to return type 'Self'"

```
class GenericEventManger<StoreEvent: EventStoreEvent> {

    var store: EventStoring

    required init(with eventStore: EventStoring) {
        self.store = eventStore
    }

    func createEvent() -> StoreEvent {
        let eventStoreEvent: EventStoreEvent = StoreEvent.createEvent(eventStore: store)

    // Then some code where I configure the event...

    try store.save(eventStoreEvent, span: .thisEvent, commit: true)
    }
}
```

On the seventh last line the error is: Cannot invoke `'createEvent'` with an argument list of type     `'(eventStore: EventStoring)'`
And on the third last it is: Cannot invoke 'save' with an argument list of type `'(StoreEvent, span: EKSpan, commit: Bool)'`

**Update** Since I adapted the recommendation from Dan another problem of the same kind arose in my implementation, so I updated my question

Comment: You would need to declare your property as `var store: StoreEvent.MatchingEventStore` otherwise there is nothing guaranteeing that is the same type as what the `createEvent` function wants.

Comment: Oh wow! Thanks! YESSA! That solved at least the problem mentioned in the headline.

Comment: come on, Bernhard, you can do this! Just look at the solution from dan and try to apply it to the other problem! Read the error message, what does it really say!? Okay... you're German and you're not really sure.. so. make sure you understand!

Comment: I believe your problem now is that your `associatedtype MatchingEventStore: EventStoring` needs a `where MatchingEventStore.Event == Self` clause.

Comment: This is much smarter than my way of forecasting the type in each message call that needs it, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I guess with the Help of Dan I figured out a solution for two of the Problems so far, but I have not testet it thoroughly yet:

First I changed the type of the `store` property of `GenericStoreManager` like Dan recommended

```
class GenericStoreManger<StoreEvent: EventStoreEvent> {

    var store: StoreEvent.MatchingEventStore

    func createEvent() -> StoreEvent {
    let eventStoreEvent: EventStoreEvent = StoreEvent.createEvent(eventStore: store)

    // Then some code where I configure the event...

    try store.save(eventStoreEvent as! StoreEvent.MatchingEventStore.Event, span: .thisEvent, commit: true)
}

    ...

}
```

and than I changed how I get my return value in `extension EKEvent: EventStoreEvent` so it would work also whit subclasses of EKEvent

```
extension EKEvent: EventStoreEvent {
    typealias MatchingEventStore = EKEventStore

    static func createEvent(eventStore: MatchingEventStore) -> Self {
        return self.init(eventStore: eventStore) 
    }
}
```